# Truly understanding lapply et al

Tags: r

I have been using R for a long time and am very happy using the map-family of functions as well as rowwise. I really just don't *get* the apply-family, even after reading many a tutorial. Right now it's very much up to chance if I get any apply function to work, and if I do, I'm not sure why it did in that case. Could anyone give an intuitive explanation of the syntax? E.g. why does the code below fail?

```
stupid_function = function(x,y){
  a = sum(x,y)
  b = max(x,y)
  return(list(MySum=a,MyMax=b))
}

mtcars %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(using_rowwise = list(stupid_function(vs, am))) %>%
  unnest_wider(using_rowwise)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(using_map = pmap(list(vs,am),stupid_function)) %>%
  unnest_wider(using_map)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(using_lapply = lapply(list(vs,am), stupid_function))
```

Using rowwise and pmap I get what I want/expect. But the last line yields the following error:

```
 Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `using_lapply`.
x argument "y" is missing, with no default
i Input `using_lapply` is `lapply(list(vs, am), stupid_function)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: `lapply` isn't equivalent to `pmap`, it's equivalent to `map`, so your `using_map` example that actually uses `pmap` isn't a good comparison. `lapply` iterates over it's first argument. You want to iterate over 2 arguments.

Comment: You mention many tutorials, but in case you haven't seen it the FAQ [on apply functions here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/903061) is my favorite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lapply()` function has the following usage (from `?lapply`).

```
lapply(X, FUN, ...)
```

The `X` argument is a list or vector or data.frame - something with elements. The `FUN` argument is some function. `lapply` then applies the `FUN` to each element of `X` and returns the outputs in a list. The first element of this list is `FUN(X[1])`and the second is `FUN(X[2])`.

In your example, `lapply(list(vs,am), stupid_function)`, `lapply` is trying to apply `stupid_function` to `vs` and then to `am`. However, `stupid_function` appears to require two arguments. This is where the `...` comes in. You pass additional arguments to `FUN` here. You just need to name them correctly. So, in your case, you would use `lapply(vs, stupid_function, y = am)`.

However, this isn't really what you want either. This will use all `am` as the second argument and not iterate over `am`. `lapply` only iterates over one variable, not two. You want to use a `map` function for this or you need to do something like the following:

```
lapply(1:nrow(mtcars) function(x) {stupid_function(mtcars$vs[x], mtcars$am[x]})
```

Comment: This is a good answer up until the end. With `rowwise` or `pmap`, OP is trying to get `stupid_function(vs[1], am[1])`, `stupid_function(vs[2], am[2])`, .... This isn't cleanly possible with `lapply`, to iterate over two inputs in parallel. The base R equivalent would be `Map`.

Comment: Your recommended fix of `lapply(vs, stupid_function, y = am)` will give `stupid_function(vs[1], am)`, `stupid_function(vs[2], am)`, ...

Comment: @GregorThomas - Good catch. I updated my answer to incorporate this point and provide a way to do this with `lapply` if one desperately felt they had to.